# Clear Spark Job history from spark master UI

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-hive

I'm working on spark, and I want to clear my spark master UI by clearing out all the previous Failed/Finished Jobs. I'm unable to figure out how to do this? I've tried deleting logs from hdfs but the job entries still show up on UI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the master spark process.
from `sbin` dir of spark,
run `./stop-master.sh` and `./start-master.sh`
It should fix.